# Change D3 line style back to regular

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

This question might be really simple but for some reason I can't figure it out, or find anything online about it.

I create the following dashed lines like so:

```
   linkContainer.enter()
        .append("line")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
        .attr("class", "link")
        .on("click", clickLine);
```

What I want to do, is when the line is clicked, I want to change it back to a continuous line, i.e. no more dashes.

```
function clickLine() {
    d3.select(this).transition()
     .duration(750)
     .style("stroke", "lightsteelblue");
}
```

Is there any style feature to transition the line from dashed to continuous? Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a transition, I would modify the `stroke-dasharray` value to contain no gaps anymore -- the first number is the (relative) length of the dash and the second of the gap. So all you need to do is set the second number to 0:

```
d3.select(this).transition()
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,0");
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zLyx9xw9/).